# Networkstream Read throws an error when client gets closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#

I've read similar questions but I could not get the solutions to work. I have a Server that created a `ClientManager` that handles sending and writing data.

The critical part that is causing a bug is this are right here:

```
    private void StartReceive(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        String data = null;
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        while (this.socket.Connected)
        {

            int i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            if (i != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);


                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        this.Disconnect();
    }
```

Specifically this: `int i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

My client is connected and sends a message, then I close the client application the server hangs on this line. I'm not sure how to handle a sudden disconnect, I assumed that the Read bytes would be 0 and it would disconnect out of the while loop, but I was mistaken.